# What is the net (absorbable) carb content of Psyllium Husk?

Tags: bread, nutrient-composition, low-carb, fiber, carbohydrates

I want to make ketogenic bread with Psyllium Husk. I am confused from looking online at the nutritional value of psyllium husk.

[Some websites](https://www.realfoodsource.com/product/organic-psyllium-husk-wee-eco-pack-250g/) reports in the nutritional values that it has only `1.7g` of carbohydrates per 100g of product. [Other sites](https://www.calorieking.com/us/en/foods/f/calories-in-grains-psyllium-husks-whole/ulMeTdZzSi2_gu34XCf5iw) state that 100g of product have `80g` of carbs.

This is really confusing. My questions are:

1. Are there different psyllium husks processing methods that produce different carbs values?
2. are there brands that report 80g of carbs just because they include the total carbs of psyllium husk including fiber (which is a carbohydrate), but since fiber is indigestible those carbs are not going to be digested? (Hence why some brands reports only 1/2g of carbs on their label).
3. Is there any absorbable carbs difference between psyllium husk and psyllium husk powder?

Comment: I don't really know if this is on topic here, but I answered nonetheless, hope it helps!

Comment: Welcome to SA!  However, requests for nutritional advice are off-topic for this board.  See: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @FuzzyChef this is not a question about nutritional advice though, it's a question about nutritional facts. It actually falls under the category of 'food selection and use' under a specific diet. I am not asking 'how healthy Psyllium Husk is' but factual information about this product for whether it can be selected under a diet, which is not an opinion on health, but a fact.

Comment: It's potentially a fact, but that doesn't make it on-topic for a board about *cooking*, any more than asking about the real vitamin content of various brands of multivitamin would be.  You really want an SE about health.

Comment: And ... you are, in fact, asking about how healthful Psyllium Husk is in this question.

Comment: @FuzzyChef no, i am not. there is not even the word health in my question.  I am asking about factual information for selecting food to cook a recipe (bread). Provide a valid argument, or please accept the fact that you are wrong.

Comment: ... I think the question is fine, but the title is misleading. You're actually just asking about the carb/net carb content of psyllium Husk. The keto-ness or not isn't really relevant.

Comment: @kitukwfyer thank you for the feedback i changed the question title and tags

Answer (score 6):

There are two carb count, total carbs (including fibre) and net carbs (excluding fibre). There are also two types of fibre and they are not always noted in the labelling, although that's mostly irrelevant for this question.

Another parameter that changes is the "serving size", in your example you can get 0.5g of net carbs if your serving size is 5g (a tablespoon) and in fact that's the case if you check out the serving size on your link.

Here is the USDA data for psyllium husk powder: https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/fdc-app.html#/food-details/1742558/nutrients

Now, can different brands and treatments and origins can have different distribution of carbs, for sure! Try to buy brands you trust and follow their label, as it supposedly comes from lab testing that specific product.

The USDA link above shows that that NOW branded powder has about 11 grams of net carbs on 100 grams of powder.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer! One question I have: where did you see net carbs on the usda link? I can only see 88.89g of carbohydrates in 100g of psyllium husk. Also there is 66g of fiber. So how much "absorbed carbs" are there in psyllium husk based on this nutritional value table of the usda?

Comment: I think they are doing total carbs -  total fibre, so 88.89 - (67 + 11) = 10.89.  That site is inaccurate though, it is claiming that there are 16.6...g of iron in 100g husks.

Comment: Yes, that's the calculation, if there is no net carbs but total carbs and fiber, the net carbs are equal to total minus fibre.

Regarding the accuracy, I think that site just registers what's on labels, so that would mean that the NOW brand of powdered psyllium husk is inaccurate (a real possiblility!), just pointing the blame to the right place :-)

Comment: Well, either that or they mispalced the comma when putting the data in... Although this label mentions it's 10% https://www.amazon.com/NOW-Foods-Psyllium-Husks-Package/dp/B00IT6ICNO